# How to get more verbose output from "ng test" configuration

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-devkit

In short, I am looking for a way to get more verbose output from `ng test`.

I am not looking for more test output, but more verbose feedback on the configuration.

I am trying to configure a project, and I get very little feedback from the CLI when something is incorrectly configured.

For example, when running `ng test`, I currently get a chrome window hosting jasmine, but with 0 specs found, and a **404** for [http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/main.js](http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js).

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Do you have any thoughts on this

Comment: Does maybe [karma-verbose-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-verbose-reporter) help?

Comment: I got past the issue I was having, and have not yet tried the above.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: @bnieland Running into same wall. Any tips on how you solved the issue?

Comment: Finally got past my problem by using ng-cli to bootstrap a new project and isolating one simple spec file to run there (had around 120 tests in a project that used Angular4 and angular-seed). Turns out the problems were all related to typescript thus the test runner didn't even bother to do anything.